# How to split image folder into test/training/validation sets and at the same time I have to add annotation files for val and test together?

Tags: database, machine-learning, deep-learning, training-data

I have a very large folder, contains 19 folders, each folder contains images for a single class, I would like to split them into training/testing/validation sets; at the same time I have to add an annotation file for validation and testing together to train the model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for split :

```html
import splitfolders

# Split with a ratio.
# To only split into training and validation set, set a tuple to `ratio`, i.e, `(.8, .2)`.
splitfolders.ratio("/home/marouane/dev/mdl-py-classification/model/data", output="/home/marouane/dev/mdl-py-classification/model/data_s",
    seed=1337, ratio=(.4, .1, .5), group_prefix=None, move=False) # default values
```

for annotation :

```html
import os
import numpy as np
import shutil
import pandas as pd


def train_test_split(name):
    """
    parameter : name of the folder
    return : text file
    """

    classes_dir = ["advert","box_start_horse","end_carriage","end_horse","group_heat_carriage","group_heat_horse","heat_carriage","heat_horse","interview",
    "orthogonal_start_carriage","orthogonal_start_horse","paddock","presenters","race_carriage","race_horse","slide","truck_start_carriage","walking_horse","winnerslide"
            ]

    dir = '/home/marouane/dev/mdl-py-classification/model/data_s/'+name+"/"

    destFile = '/home/marouane/dev/mdl-py-classification/model/data_s/'+name+".txt"

    for cls in classes_dir:
        path = dir + cls
        files = os.listdir(path)
        for file in files :
            with open(destFile, 'a') as f:
                f.write(cls+"/" +file +" " +str(classes_dir.index(cls))+"\r\n")


train_test_split("val")
train_test_split("test")
```